# Why does java need type identifiers?

Tags: java

Since every class in java is a subclass of the Object, and variables in java are not objects themselves but instead are object references, why does java make type specification compulsory, when the Object type could be made implicit? The only time it seems necessary is when using the simple data types.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all. Could you post a snippet of code where you think a "type specification" is unnecessary?

Comment: To be clear: You want variables to default to `Object` and not type inference? Why would this be desirable? You can't do many useful things with an `object`. Or do you want to know why java is statically and not dynamically typed?

Comment: Could you please share some (fake) code to explain what you mean? How could we use the object's methods if we don't know its type?

Comment: @Likhit You can't answer "yes" to an either-or question.

Comment: @CodeInChaos my earlier comment was in reference to your comment before you edited it. But anyway, i get it now, i got confused and mixed up statically and dynamically typed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a variable is of type `Object`, the compiler will not let you use the variable as any other type (unless you cast it).
This is called type safety.

For example:

```
Object str = "abc";

s.toUpppercase();  //Compiler error
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. Java does it because.. this is how the language was defined.
this boils down to what was considered good practice when the language was designed (nearly 20 years ago), and also with complier ease of development.

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), a language which is closely related to Java (runs on the same JVM), does not require explicit type identifiers in most cases.
the downside is the scala compiler is much slower (for this among other reasons).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably Java is an object oriented language used in large projects and created by reasonable company. Having such strong typing decrease amount of potential bugs, that you are able to remove on compilation level.

btw.
In the .NET product you have such thing as `var x`. But it can be used only locally in method body. But this is only a compiler sugar for developers. So Java is only a example of strong typed language.

Answer (score -1):

Java is a strongly typed language. The types are needed to be able to compile code and validate types compatibility at compile time.

Weakly typed languages do not have types. For example when you say `var x` in JavaScript you just define variable. Then value of any type may be assigned there. This means that if for example your code has bug and you assign string to this variable and then try to divide this variable by 2 (`y = x / 2`) the script will just fail at runtime. Java will not allow you to compile such code.

There is the principle: the bug costs x during development, x*10 during QA and x*100 if it arrives to production. Compiler and strongly typed languages allow to decrease number of (stupid) bugs that arrive to QA and therefore make software development easier, faster and cheaper.

Comment: I'd use `static` vs. `dynamic` typing. `strong` and `weak` aren't well defined, and some dynamically typed languages are often called strongly typed. And even dynamically typed languages have types. For example *values* in javascript can be strings, objects, numbers,etc.

Comment: I see, but then how does Python implement such variables(although it's said to be strongly typed)?

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, java is statically typed. Some people prefer the compile time type checking static typing offers, some prefer the flexibility of dynamic typing.